# Question in the proof of Caratheodory's theorem

Tags: measure-theory

First, let me recall Caratheodory's theorem:

**Theorem (Caratheodory).** Let $\mathcal{M}:=\{E:E\subseteq X,\theta A=\theta(A\cap E)+\theta(A\cap E^c),\forall A\subseteq X\}$ be the class of measurable sets. Then $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$, and the restriction of the outer measure $\theta$ to the class of measurable sets $\mathcal{M}$ is a complete measure.

Suppose that I already proved that $\mathcal{M}$ is an algebra of sets, i.e., in particular, that $E\cup F$ is measurable. Then, by induction on $n$, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} E_i$ is measurable, that is:

$\theta(A)=\theta(A\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} E_i))+\theta(A\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} E_i)^c)$

$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta(A\cap E_i)+\theta(A\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} E_i)^c)$ if $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}E_i=\emptyset$

$\geq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta(A\cap E_i)+\theta(A\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} E_i)^c)$ because $(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} E_i)^c\supseteq (\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} E_i)^c$

? $\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\theta(A\cap E_i)+\theta(A\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i)^c)$

$\geq\theta(A\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} E_i))+\theta(A\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} E_i)^c)$ because $\theta$ is countably sub-additive.

My question concerns line 4, and the justification of going from

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta(A\cap E_i)$ to $\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\theta(A\cap E_i)$

In my textbook (Jain and Gupta, 1986, p.70), the argument is that we do not increase the value of $A$ if we take the limit of the sum to $+\infty$. Could anybody provide me with a better explanation, for it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG, assume $\theta(A)<\infty$, otherwise we have done.

From what you have done, $\theta(A)-\theta(A\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} E_i)^c)\geq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta(A\cap E_i)\, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\theta(A\cap E_i)$ is a monotone increasing sequence in extended real number, the limit must exists, and LHS is a constant, hence let $n\to \infty$
$$\theta(A)-\theta(A\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} E_i)^c)\geq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\theta(A\cap E_i)$$
That is 
$$\theta(A)\geq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\theta(A\cap E_i)+\theta(A\cap(\bigcup_{i=1}^{+\infty} E_i)^c)$$